# Specifying Range of RSolve

Tags: recursion

When I input

```
RSolve[{0 == q[n + 1]^2 + 3 q[n + 1] + 2 q[n + 1] q[n] - 6 q[n] + q[n]^2, q[0] == 1}, q[n], n]
```

I get two complicated-looking complex solutions:

```
{{q[n] -> 1/4 I ((-2 + I) + 4 I^n - (2 + 5 I) I^(2 n) - (2 + 2 I) I^n Sqrt[5] + (2 + 2 I) I^(2 n) Sqrt[5])}, {q[n] -> -(1/4)I ((2 - I) - 4 I^n + (2 + 5 I) I^(2 n) - (2 + 2 I) I^n Sqrt[5] + (2 + 2 I) I^(2 n) Sqrt[5])}}
```

There should be just one solution for each $n$ that is between 0 and 1, and I'd like only to see those. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RSolve` result is bogus.  You can simply plug into the recurrence relation to see that it's not satisfied.  It's easy to roll your own, though.  I guess the relationship between $q_1$ and $q_2$ can be expressed as

```
q2[q1_] = q2 /. Solve[q2^2 + 3 q2 + 2 q2*q1 - 6 q1 + q1^2 == 0, q2]
(* Out: {(-3 - 2 q1 - 3 Sqrt[1 + 4 q1])/2, (-3 - 2 q1 + 3 Sqrt[1 + 4 q1])/2} *)
```

We can examine the following plot to see that indeed, given a $q_1 \in [0,1]$, exactly one of these $q_2$s is also in $[0,1]$.

```
Plot[Evaluate[q2[q1]], {q1, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

In fact, if you're used to the color scheme, you can see that it's the *second* solution that is again in the unit interval.  Thus, we can define `q` as

```
Clear[q];
q[0] = 1;
q[n_] := q[n] =  (-3 - 2 q[n - 1] + 3 Sqrt[1 + 4 q[n - 1]])/2;
Table[q[n], {n, 0, 2}]
N[Table[q[n], {n, 0, 8}]]
```

[image]

More generally, the recursive definition of `q` might involve a `Select` command, if you don't have such a simple way to chose which branch to follow.

Comment: Any idea what's wrong with RSolve?

Comment: @QuinnCulver Not definitively, but it hardly seems shocking, given the branch cuts that are bound to arise with a quadratic recurrence.

Comment: What I want is an exact expression for $q(n)$. Any idea(s)?

Comment: @QuinnCulver I tried `FindSequenceFunction` without success but I really see no reason to think that such an expression exists.  I can tell you that the sequence converges monotonically down to $3/4$ with approximate multiplier $1/2$ but not much more.

Comment: And shouldn't RSolve at least get $q(1)$ correct since there's no branching yet?

Comment: @QuinnCulver Well, it oughtta get the whole damn thing correct, no? If you're going to use a black box, you'd better check your results and, in this case, they don't check out.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'approximate multiplier $1/2$'?

Comment: @QuinnCulver I mean that $|x_{n}-3/4|<(|x_{n-1}-(3/4)|)/2$. In words, the distance between $x_n$ and $3/4$ is a little less than half the distance between $x_{n-1}$ and $3/4$. You can verify this numerically by looking at `Ratios[N[Table[q[n],{n,0,9}]-3/4]]` - you'll see a sequence converging to $1/2$. Analytically, you're iterating $f(x)=(-2x+3\sqrt{4x+1}-3)/2$ which has a fixed point at $x=3/4$ satisfying $f'(3/4)=1/2$.